# .net datagridview value from database change cell value when loading

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, double, money-format

I have a datagridview and it load data from database. The SPENDING_SUM is double in database, but I want change it to money in the datagridview (for example, if the database value is 1234567.00, what I want to display in the datagridview is 
$1,234,567.00). Don't know how to convert the value.

The related code is:

```
       Using connObj As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.dbConnectionString)
            connObj.Open()


            querySql = "SELECT UPPER(USER_ID) AS 'USER ID', UPPER(USER_NAME) AS 'USER NAME', " & vbCrLf &
                      "CONVERT(varchar,JOIN_DATE, 103) AS 'JOIN DATE'," & vbCrLf &
                      "SPENDING_SUM AS 'SPENDING SUM' FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = " & vbCrLf &


            querySql = querySql + userName.Text

            Try
                adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(querySql, connObj)
                adapter.Fill(ds)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            Catch ex As Exception
                logger.Error(ex.ToString)
            End Try

            connObj.Close()
        End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the filed values with preceding dollar($) symbol you need not convert the field to money instead you can use something  like

```
 querySql = "SELECT UPPER(USER_ID) AS 'USER ID', UPPER(USER_NAME) AS 'USER NAME', " & vbCrLf &
                      "CONVERT(varchar,JOIN_DATE, 103) AS 'JOIN DATE'," & vbCrLf & 
                      " '$' + convert(varchar(100),SPENDING_SUM) AS 'SPENDING SUM' FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = " & vbCrLf &
```

if you want to convert to money,you can use a cast operator like

```
 querySql = "SELECT UPPER(USER_ID) AS 'USER ID', UPPER(USER_NAME) AS 'USER NAME', " & vbCrLf &
                      "CONVERT(varchar,JOIN_DATE, 103) AS 'JOIN DATE'," & vbCrLf &
                      "cast(SPENDING_SUM as money) AS 'SPENDING SUM' FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = " & vbCrLf &
```

anyways i prefer the first solution as it will provide better query performances.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although the second solution convert the value to money, I still cannot see the "$" and "," inside. The first solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a control named lblDisplay where you want to display this here is the simple code.

```
 lblDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", SPENDING_SUM)
```

For simple use try this example.

```
 Dim Numbers As Double = 1234567.0
 lblDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", Numbers)
```

Hope this answered your question.